# How to properly initialize and use the monaco editor tokenizer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

As the title states, I've been searching for a week now on how to get the tokenizer to work. I.e. if I do something like:

```
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor-core";

const code = "export const myFunc = () => console.log('hello world');"
const tokens = monaco.editor.tokenize(code, "typescript");
console.log("TOKENS ", tokens);
```

I'll get the tokenized *lines* identified, but within each actual line you'll see that the token array is empty.

Import as you'd like here, either from `monaco-editor-core` or `monaco-editor` - you'll find the same result.

My current workaround is calling the tokenizer on the `window` object of `monaco` (I'm using React, so I could otherwise import it from the module, though I found this hack only worked with accessing `window.monaco` within a 1-second timeout, like so:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  (window as any).monaco.editor.tokenize(
    `export const dummyFunction = () => {
  console.log('hello world')
}`,
    "typescript"
  );
}, 1000);
```

Only *then* can you successfully call `monaco.editor.tokenize`.

There is also [an open GitHub issue about this problem](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3448).

I would be grateful if anyone can point me in a direction to get the tokenizer to work without my `setTimeout` hack.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait for the worker initialize

```
const workerReady = new Deferred()

self.MonacoEnvironment = {
    getWorker: async function (workerId, label) {
        switch (label) {
            case 'typescript':
            case 'javascript': {
                const {default: TsWorker} = await import('monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker?worker')
                workerReady.resolve()

                return new TsWorker()
            }
            default: {
                const {default: EditorWorker} = await import('monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker')
                workerReady.resolve()

                return new EditorWorker()
            }
        }
    },
}
```

then just wait for worker before tokenization

```
await workerReady
```

Comment: What is `Deferred`? Why not just store the promise returned by `getWorker`?

Comment: Deferred is my implementation deferred promise pattern, but you're absolutely right, store a returned promise is better.